# Matplotlib arranging data by a list of strings to get labels in order (on an ax not a plt)

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, scatter-plot, axis-labels

*My use requires the AX feature not PLT (most answers ive found focused on PLT which does NOT have the same method calls)*

What I'm looking for is to be able to organize the x-values...
A) in order by A, B, C, D, E, F 
B) to display A and C though they have no data points associated with it

I'm sure its something simple I'm missing... Here's a test example of it

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#desired x axis labels    
x_label_order = ["A","B","C","D","E","F"]

#data to be plotted
x=["B","E","D","F"]
y=[1,2,3,4]

#creates graph    
fig, ax = plt.subplots (1,1)
ax.scatter(x,y)

#assuming this is where changes need to be made?
ax.set_xticks(x_label_order)
ax.set_xticklabels(x_label_order)


plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow.

For a Scatterplot, typically both `x` and `y` are numerical. But `matplotlib` is smart (or not) enough to convert the string labels to running numbers automatically.

If you want to preserve the sequence, when you plot, you need to convert `x` to its corresponding index location first:

```
x_label_order = ["A","B","C","D","E","F"]
x = ["B","E","D","F"]
x = [x_label_order.index(group) for group in x]
```

Then after you plot, set `xticks` at the numerical location, and pass the labels to it:

```
ax.set_xticks(list(range(len(x_label_order))))
ax.set_xticklabels(x_label_order)
```

and you should get what you require:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, kind programmer!

Comment: I was able to incorporate it into my real program! Thank you. I have not used the .index() method before but its pretty straight forward! For loops inside of list brackets still messes with my brain (i want to use a for loop and then append to the list) but this is soooo much cleaner looking.